# multi day events in the core?

Tags: civievent, core

Are there any plans for multi day event support in the core?  I see the extension for this is for vers <= 4.2.  I'm considering trying to update it, but don't want to redouble another's efforts.  Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about the recurring events?

Comment: No, I'm asking about multi-day events.   https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-multiday-event

Comment: Hi Peter, its something we've been approached about a few times, especially with regards to recurring events and sessions. Its not a small task and as yet we haven't had anyone step forward!

Comment: Ouch, I see that it's really a huge task since all the data is stored in Drupal instead of Civi.   I guess that decision was made because the Field Collections module was leveraged to make it happen.  I and a friend re-imagined a way to do this completely in CiviCRM.   Our use case is selling courses.  Each course is essentially a product that gets it's own contribution page.  Then the events get either custom data (integer) or a database field that references the contribution-page-id.   That way sessions are just events.  hooks go in events and contib pages to reference each other.  Thoughts?

Comment: Peter - did you ever do something towards this?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion we did, but not entirely in civi.  One of our board members is a JS person and developed a webapp the that displays civi events on our squarespace site.  I developed a module that creates a json feed of civi events that his webapp consumes.  In civi we created an event type "course" and use the repeating event feature for class instances.   Events are displayed based on event type.   If you want to look at it, bug me and I'll get the rest of it commited. it's OSS

Comment: Thanks for the reply